# Updating the coverage report without overriding it

Tags: python, code-coverage

The way I create a coverage report is by doing:

```
source coverage_setup.sh
setenv COVERAGE_PROCESS_START .coveragerc
myscript.py --f 1
unsetenv COVERAGE_PROCESS_START
```

The setup script just adds the coverage module (3.6.3) to the `PATH` and sets the `PYTHONPATH` to the coverage module.

I have a (non-python) script that executes `myscript.py` multpul times, for example:

```
myscript.py --f 1
myscript.py --f 2
myscript.py --f 3
```

I want each execustion to update the `.coveragerc` file and not to override it. I could not find a flag to do so. I also tried to change the `COVERAGE_PROCESS_START` to be:

```
source coverage_setup.sh
setenv COVERAGE_PROCESS_START .coveragerc1
myscript.py --f 1
setenv COVERAGE_PROCESS_START .coveragerc2
myscript.py --f 2
setenv COVERAGE_PROCESS_START .coveragerc3
myscript.py --f 3
unsetenv COVERAGE_PROCESS_START
```

And then to merge the reports. But the coverage report fails with the following error (when executing `myscript.py`):

```
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
CoverageException: Couldn't read '.coveragerc1' as a config file
```

Is there a way to tell the coverage module to update the same report and not to override it?
If not, is there a workaround that could work?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need COVERAGE_PROCESS_START if you are simply running a Python file.  Do this:

```
coverage run myscript.py --f 1
```

Second, you can use the `--append` flag to accumulate data into a data file rather than starting over for each run:

```
coverage run --append myscript.py --f 1
```